# Super CSV Java all data not written into csv

Tags: java, supercsv

I have a list `<Bean>`of size 944, when the data is written into the CSV file, everything is working fine but I see only 940 records. I don't know what is the issue. Can anybody please  help me?

```
static void writeCSVFile(String fileName, List<GPR> listGPR) {
    ICsvBeanWriter beanWriter = null;
    CellProcessor[] processors = new CellProcessor[] {
        new NotNull(), 
        new Optional(),
        new Optional(),
        new Optional(), 
        new Optional(), 
        new Optional(),
        new Optional(),
    };

    try {
        beanWriter = new CsvBeanWriter(new FileWriter(fileName),
            CsvPreference.STANDARD_PREFERENCE);

        final String[] header = {"Number","Project Type","Actual Start Date","Actual End Date","Owner","Name","Description"};

        final String[] dataMapping = new String[] { "number", "projectType", "actualStrtDate", "actualEndDate", "owner", "name","description"};

        beanWriter.writeHeader(header);
        for (GPR gpr : listGPR) {
            beanWriter.write(gpr, dataMapping, processors);
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error writing the CSV file: " + ex);
    } finally {
        if (beanWriter != null) {
            try {
                beanWriter.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("Error closing the writer: " + ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably neglected to close the writer properly. Use the try-with-resources statement. Post a complete example. And indent your code.

Comment: Brian,I have closed the  writer

Comment: Most certainly not. Can you include the full relevant code ?

Comment: I have updated  my code, please check and let me know where have I went wrong

Comment: Well in principle you did ok. To simplify your code, use a `try` with resources. Your exception handling is also very weak, usually outputting a message in the console does not really help. At least print the stacktrace to help debugging when this happens

Comment: I have addedd print stack trace and tested ,I dont see any error after execution.Now I see only 929 records instead of 944 records. Also the number of records that is written into csv is varying everytime I execute the code.Can anybody please let me know what went wrong

Comment: I have addedd print stack trace and tested ,I dont see any error after execution.Now I see only 929 records instead of 944 records. Also the number of records that is written into csv is varying everytime I execute the code.we are using java 5 so I cant use try-with-resources which is available from java 7 onwards.Can anybody please let me know what went wrong.

Comment: Looking at your code I can't see any issue there. Why not print the size of the list at the start of the method, and `beanWriter.getRowNumber()` at the end - the row number should be 1 more than the size of the List (it includes the header).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and putting my code into try catch block and primarily closing the writeToCSV(writeToCSV.close()) object reference helped me in getting all records.